# Translate a table to a hierarchical dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a table of the form:

```
A1, B1, C1, (value)
A1, B1, C1, (value)
A1, B1, C2, (value)
A1, B2, C1, (value)
A1, B2, C1, (value)
A1, B2, C2, (value)
A1, B2, C2, (value)
A2, B1, C1, (value)
A2, B1, C1, (value)
A2, B1, C2, (value)
A2, B1, C2, (value)
A2, B2, C1, (value)
A2, B2, C1, (value)
A2, B2, C2, (value)
A2, B2, C2, (value)
```

I'd like to work with it in python as a dictionary, of form:

```
H = {
    'A1':{
        'B1':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] },
        'B2':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] },
        'B3':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] }
    },
    'A2':{
        'B1':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] },
        'B2':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] },
        'B3':{
            'C1':[],'C2':[],'C3':[] }
    }
}
```

So that `H[A][B][C]` yields a particular unique list of values.  For small dictionaries, I might just define the structure in advance as above, but I am looking for an efficient way to iterate over the table and build a dictionary, without specifying the dictionary keys ahead of time.

Comment: Do you always look up a triple of A, B, C values? If so, you'd be better off with a single `dict` using those triples as keys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
input = [('A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'Value'), (...)]

from collections import defaultdict

tree = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)))
#Alternatively you could use partial() rather than lambda:
#tree = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, partial(defaultdict, list)))

for x, y, z, value in input:
    tree[x][y][z].append(value)
```

Comment: Note that if table is a text file, you'll want something like ``with open("table") as file:`` ``input = [line.split() for line in file]``.

Comment: An alternative to using lambdas here is to use ``functools.partial()``: ``tree = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, partial(defaultdict, list)))`` - I find this clearer, but that might just be me.

Answer (score 5):

If you ever only access H[A][B][C] (that is, never H[A] oder H[A][B] alone), I'd suggest a IMO cleaner solution: Use Tuples as defaultdict Index:

```
from collections import defaultdict
h = defaultdict(list)
for a, b, c, value in input:
    h[a, b, c].append(value)
```

Comment: This is a very valid (and elegant) solution too, although it does require that he doesn't want to access the sub-dicts separately. (edited to remove some extra indentation, unneeded brackets, and PEP-8ifying the variable names).

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution.  In this case, I need to access sub-dictionaries, but I didn't specify that in the question.  This will be extremely elegant if this case exists in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {}
for (a, b, c, value) in your_table_of_tuples:
   d.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b,{}).setdefault(c,[]).append(value)
```

Comment: Why use ``setdefault()`` over a ``defaultdict``?

Comment: I would argue it's a lot uglier when you use it.

Comment: Which is why I offered up my ``functools.partial()`` based solution in the comments. ;) (Which could be expanded out for readability).

Answer (score 1):

But what if you don't have three levels but maybe ten levels? Pretty sure you can do it with a while loop but this is what I came up with (warning: extreme exploitation of mutability and pointers)

```py
def build_tree(data, categories):
    """Build a dependency tree based on a Pandas DataFrame and an
    ordered list of levels.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
        A DataFrame containing the table to derive tree from
    categories : array_like
        An ordered, sliceable list of column names to include in tree

    Returns
    -------
    hierarchy : dict
        A standard Python dictionary
        """
    hierarchy = {}
    def expand(data, categories, current_level):
        if len(categories) == 2:
            for value in data[categories[0]].unique():
                current_level[value] = data.loc[data[categories[0]] == value, categories[1]]
        else:
            for value in data[categories[0]].unique():
                current_level[value] = {e: None for e in data.loc[data[categories[0]] == value, categories[1]].unique()}
                expand(data.loc[data[categories[0]] == value, :], categories[1:], current_level[value])
    expand(data, categories, hierarchy)
    return hierarchy
```

I feel like some of the for loops could be nicer but can't they always?

This is also dependent on a single key/value pair being found at the bottom of your hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for any number of keys:

```
def parse_table_to_tree(table):
    tree = dict()
    for row in table:
        tree = attach_leaf(tree, row[:-1], row[-1])
    return tree


def attach_leaf(tree:dict, keys:list, value):
    d = tree
    for i, key in enumerate(keys):
        if i < len(keys)-1:
            d = d.setdefault(key, {})
        else:
            d[key] = value
    return tree

tree = parse_table_to_tree(
    [
        ['a', 'b', 'c', []],
        ['a', 'b', 'd', []],
        ['a', 'f', 'a', []]
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you start from this...

```
keys = [
    ('A1', 'B1', 'C1'), 
    ('A1', 'B1', 'C2'),
    ('A1', 'B2', 'C1')
]
values = [0, 1, 2]
```

... you can easily create a nested dictionary with `NestedDict`

```
from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict

nd = NestedDict()
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    nd[key] = value
```

To get the result as a dictionary:

```
>>> nd.to_dict()
{'A1': {'B1': {'C1': 0, 'C2': 1}, 'B2': {'C1': 2}}}
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) simply `pip install ndicts`